# ink Smart Contract "dies" after the node runtime update

Tags: ink, runtime-upgrade, upgrade

I am working on Substrate node update.

During the testing, I found out that the deployed smart contract ([incrementer, tag: v3.0.0-rc4](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/v3.0.0-rc4/examples/incrementer)) "dies" during the node updates from:

1. [v0.8.27](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-release-v0.8.27) to [v0.8.28](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.8.28);
2. [v0.8.28](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.8.28) to [v0.8.29](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.8.29);
3. [v0.8.29](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.8.29) to [v0.8.30](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.8.30).

What does "dies" mean?
The network sees the SC but during execution the following errors are received:

1. In Polkadot.js apps' console;

   ```
   RPC-CORE: rentProjection(address: AccountId, at?: BlockHash): Option<BlockNumber>:: 3: The contract is a tombstone and doesn't have any storage.
   ```
2. Transaction fails in the Network.

   ```
   DispatchError
   {
     Module: {
       index: 17,
       error: 12
     }
   }

   type
   contracts.NotCallable

   details
   The contract that was called is either no contract at all (a plain account),  or is a tombstone.

   DispatchInfo
   {
     weight: 0,
     class: Normal,
     paysFee: Yes
   }
   ```

At the same time:

1. I am able to deploy SC each time after node runtime update and it is working as expected;
2. Starting [v0.8.30](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.8.30) -> [v0.9.0](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/dc9acd2d74a5451a63e34060a4c7869021780b3e) this issue is not reproducing (tested up to [0.9.3](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.3) including).

Does somebody have any ideas on how to avoid "dying"?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you were upgrading between `pallet-contracts` versions which offered no upgrade path. Neither they offered compatibility for already deployed contracts nor did we include storage migrations.

This changed with `v0.8.30`. You still need to make sure to include the storage migrations contained in `pallet-contracts` in your runtime.