# After doing runtime upgrade getting contract not found in substrate contracts ui

Tags: runtime-upgrade, substrate-node, blockchain, contracts

I am doing runtime upgrade of substrate blockchain from `0.9.36 --> 0.9.37 --->0.9.43` . And i have some contracts deployed on the running blockchain which is running on 36 version  . After doing runtime upgrade from `0.9.36 ---> 0.9.39` version . I tried to check contracts on my chain. When I tried to call them through `substrate contracts-ui`   (on my chain which is now runtime upgraded to 39 version from 36 version)   it  is showing contracts not found  and I am unable to call my deployed contracts . The same is also happening on my other chain which I  runtime upgraded from `43 version` to `1.0.0 version` can someone please tell me how to solve this
issue.

[image: error i am getting in ui after upgrading]

```
  update
```

i have tried these steps

1 i have added. 36 version substrate contract pallet in 39 version substrate and then ,i did  runtime upgrade of substrate blockchain which is running at 36 version substrate with contracts deployed on it  with the 39 version substrate which has 36 version contract pallet in it. and everything worked fine in this case.

i want to know where is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an issue with the storage migration.

- Are you including the storage migrations contained in `pallet-contracts` in your runtime ? (check also this [substrate issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/12794#issuecomment-1330862591) and this [SE answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/ink-smart-contract-dies-after-the-node-runtime-update/5114#5114))
- In general you need to include the migrations into the `Executive` type of your runtime (check also this [SE answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/6135/234))

More information on storage migrations you can find in this [page](https://docs.substrate.io/maintain/runtime-upgrades/#storage-migration) of the Substrate docs. Also, worth checking the [try-runtime-cli](https://github.com/paritytech/try-runtime-cli) and this [SE answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/6193/234) on testing a migration.

Another good practice is to do the runtime upgrades "one by one" and not "jump up" multiple versions during one upgrade. If you still choose to skip versions during a runtime upgrade, you have to check that there are no storage migrations between versions.

Comment: @ Dominique  i have done all the steps you mentioned but still from. `38-->39` version it is not working.  and still showing contract not found in contracts ui.