# Could not decode `ContractInfo::storage_item_deposit

Tags: smart-contract

When I am doing runtime-upgrade from `polkadot-v0.9.38` to `polkadot-v0.9.39` .I am getting one issue of smart contract in my terminal

```
  2023-09-18 11:36:25 Corrupted state at `[67, 66, 25, 62, 73, 111, 171, 126, 197, 157, 97, 94, 208, 220, 85, 48, 6, 14, 153, 229, 55, 142, 86, 37, 55, 207, 59, 201, 131, 225, 123, 145, 7, 190, 185, 213, 63, 100, 190, 13, 84, 242, 53, 215, 14, 189, 128, 119, 55, 150, 202, 102, 150, 1, 58, 100, 98, 150, 229, 140, 171, 200, 50, 44, 7, 79, 42, 165, 176, 190, 50, 220]: Error { cause: Some(Error { cause: None, desc: "Not enough data to fill buffer" }), desc: "Could not decode `ContractInfo::storage_item_deposit`" }`    
2023-09-18 11:36:27  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0xd49263641146674ccb5c71c679
```

And I have some contracts deployed on the running blockchain which is running on 36 version . After doing runtime upgrade from `0.9.38---> 0.9.39` version . I tried to check contracts on my chain. When I tried to call them through substrate contracts-ui (on my chain which is now runtime upgraded to 39 version from 36 version) it is showing contracts not found and I am unable to call my deployed contracts .

Comment: Does this help? https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9809/after-doing-runtime-upgrade-getting-contract-not-found-in-substrate-contracts-ui

Comment: Nope. @AlexBean